# How to filter depending on value of entity in related collection?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I want to filter navigation property of entity. Let's have two Poco Classes

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

}
```

Client contains navigation collection property called Products which will contain Product client is using or he has used.

and product is having year property on which client has started using product.

now I want a client who has started using product in year 2012 with those products.

Currently I am doing below wrong query

```
this.ObjectContext.Clients.Include("Products").
Where(d => d.Name =="John" && d.Products.Where(e => e.Year == 2012).Count() > 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

I know this is wrong query. I want retrieve Client with only Product having year 2012. But above query will give me client with all record of products.

Thanks in Advance for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is LINQ question, and there is relationship between Clients and Products.

```
this.ObjectContext.Clients.Where(d => d.Name =="John" && d.Products.Any(e => e.Year == 2012));
```

and if you want object that has only client and products that are Year 2012.

**Updated assuming there are setters on Name, Id, and Products.**

```
this.ObjectContext.Clients.Where(d => d.Name == "John").Select(d => new Client(){ 
Name = d.Name,
Id = d.Id,
Products = d.Products.Where(e => e.Year == 2012).ToList()
});
```

Comment: but I am having webservice which will return Client object having Products (having year 2012). So I want client object which will have only such a products which are having year 2012.

Comment: I know this can be done by select method but I want this thing achieved by client.Products navigation property.

Comment: By the way I think this is great work around to address this issue as of now.